# JavaScript table not showing

Tags: javascript, html

I'm practicing this question where I'm supposed to make a table *programatically* and although I'm not getting any errors the table is not showing.

```js
var ROWS = 13;
var COLS = 2;
 

window.onload = function go() {
     var out = document.getElementsByClassName("funky")[0];
     var table = document.createElement("table");
     table.border = 1;
     for (var i=0; i < ROWS; i += 1) {
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
            for (var j=0; j < COLS; j += 1) {
                   var col = document.createElement("td");
                   col.innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(i + j);
                   if (i % 3 == 0) {
                      col.style.color = "red";
                   } else if (i % 3 == 1) {
                      col.style.color = "green";
                   } else if ((j) % 3 == 2) {
                      col.style.color = "blue";
                   }
            } 
            table.appendChild(row);
     }
     table.appendChild(col);
}
```

Comment: [Broken code](http://meta.CodeReview.StackExchange.com/a/3650) is off-topic for this site. Please [follow the tour](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask), ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this.

```
<script>
var ROWS = 13;
var COLS = 2;


window.onload = function go() {
     var out = document.getElementsByClassName("funky")[0];
     var table = document.createElement("table");
     table.border = 1;
     for (var i=0; i < ROWS; i += 1) {
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
            for (var j=0; j < COLS; j += 1) {
                   var col = document.createElement("td");
                   col.innerHTML = i;
                   if (i % 3 == 0) {
                      col.style.color = "red";
                   } else if (i % 3 == 1) {
                      col.style.color = "green";
                   } else if ((j) % 3 == 2) {
                      col.style.color = "blue";
                   }
                   row.appendChild(col);
            } 
            table.appendChild(row);
     }
     //table.appendChild(col);
     document.body.appendChild(table);
}
</script>
```

Comment: So my only mistake was "document.body.appendChild(table);" ?

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions; this makes it hard for later clean-up.

Comment: Okay sorry, I'll delete this then?

Comment: yes you may delete, it's more like a question in stack overflow. you have to add col to row.